# Using a JOIN instead of HAVING(COUNT > n) to improve performance

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, join, group-by

I have a table of users, along with a table of "Facebook friend" relationships among them. Given a (known) list of users, I'd like to quickly find all users who are Facebook friends with 2 or more users in that group.

(This basically comes down to the question: Can I rewrite a GROUP BY/HAVING to use JOINs?)

Here's a simplified version of the schema I'm working with. I used VARCHAR here to make the user names in my sample data (below) easier to understand; IRL the relevant columns are INTs:

```
-- Simplified Schema
CREATE TABLE _users (
    user_name VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    fb_id     VARCHAR NULL UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE _fb_friends (
    id           SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name    VARCHAR NULL REFERENCES _users(user_name),
    friend_fb_id VARCHAR NULL REFERENCES _users(fb_id),
    UNIQUE (user_name, friend_fb_id)
);
```

Note that there's no (accessible) index on friend_fb_id.

Also note that the _fb_friends table is enormous - several orders of magnitude larger than the _users table - making the obvious GROUP BY/HAVING solution impossibly slow. I.E. this is not feasible:

```
-- Using GROUP BY/HAVING: Obvious solution, but way too slow.
-- Does a SEQ SCAN on the gigantic table
SELECT me.*
FROM
    _users me
    LEFT OUTER JOIN _fb_friends ff ON (
        ff.user_name = me.user_name
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN _users friend ON (
        friend.fb_id = ff.friend_fb_id
    )
GROUP BY me.user_name
HAVING COUNT(friend.user_name) >= 2;
```

I rewrote this to use JOINs, but I'm not sure the solution I came up with is valid or optimal:

```
-- Using JOINs: Way faster, but is it correct? Better way?
SELECT DISTINCT me.*
FROM (
    _users me
    LEFT OUTER JOIN _fb_friends ff1 ON (
        ff1.user_name = me.user_name
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN _fb_friends ff2 ON (
        ff2.user_name = me.user_name
        AND ff2.friend_fb_id <> ff1.friend_fb_id
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN _users friend ON (
        friend.fb_id = ff1.friend_fb_id
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN _users friend_2 ON (
        friend_2.fb_id = ff2.friend_fb_id
    )
)
WHERE (
    friend.user_name IS NOT NULL
    AND friend_2.user_name IS NOT NULL
);
```

For what it's worth, I wrote a simple test example that *seems* to work correctly. But I'm really not sure it's correct, or that I'm going about this the best way possible. Both strategies return the same users:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE _users (
    user_name VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    fb_id     VARCHAR NULL UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE _fb_friends (
    id           SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name    VARCHAR NULL REFERENCES _users(user_name),
    friend_fb_id VARCHAR NULL REFERENCES _users(fb_id)
);
INSERT INTO _users (user_name, fb_id) VALUES
    ('Bob',    'bob'),
    ('Joe',    'joe'),
    ('Will',   'will'),
    ('Marcus', 'marcus'),
    ('Mitch',  'mitch'),
    ('Rick',   'rick');
INSERT INTO _fb_friends (user_name, friend_fb_id) VALUES
    ('Bob',    'joe'),
    ('Will',   'marcus'),
    ('Joe',    'bob'),
    ('Joe',    'marcus'),
    ('Joe',    'mitch'),
    ('Marcus', 'will'),
    ('Marcus', 'joe'),
    ('Mitch',  'joe');

SELECT 'GROUP BY/HAVING' AS Strategy, me.*
FROM
    _users me
    LEFT OUTER JOIN _fb_friends ff ON (
        ff.user_name = me.user_name
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN _users friend ON (
        friend.fb_id = ff.friend_fb_id
    )
GROUP BY me.user_name
HAVING COUNT(friend.user_name) >= 2;

SELECT DISTINCT 'JOIN' AS Strategy, me.*
FROM (
    _users me
    LEFT OUTER JOIN _fb_friends ff1 ON (
        ff1.user_name = me.user_name
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN _fb_friends ff2 ON (
        ff2.user_name = me.user_name
        AND ff2.friend_fb_id <> ff1.friend_fb_id
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN _users friend ON (
        friend.fb_id = ff1.friend_fb_id
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN _users friend_2 ON (
        friend_2.fb_id = ff2.friend_fb_id
    )
)
WHERE (
    friend.user_name IS NOT NULL
    AND friend_2.user_name IS NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE _fb_friends;
DROP TABLE _users;

COMMIT;
```

So basically, my questions are:

1. Is my JOIN solution correct?
2. Is there a better/canonical way to go about this?

Indexing friend_fb_id, as well as changing the schema, are considered off-limits. I need to do the best with what I currently have.

Comment: I'm not imposing these limits, this is just the situation I have to deal with. So there's nothing "magic" here, the question is whether the query can be rephrased in a more efficient way. I haven't been able to find any examples of this JOIN strategy and wanted to get feedback from other devs.

Comment: If there is no indexes - it will be a fullscans. Fullscans slow. If you want to improve your performance - the first step is to index properly. You cannot change schema? There is no second step until first is accomplished. And I insist: what you want is "magic". You cannot get performance magically from nowhere (unless you buy more expensive hardware)

Comment: For the record, the JOIN solution does not perform a SEQ scan; if it did, it would be about as performant as the GROUP BY, and I would not have asked the question. In a prod DB w/>100 million rows, the GROUP BY strategy takes 1-30 minutes, while the JOIN takes about 3 seconds.

Comment: "For the record, the JOIN solution does not perform a SEQ scan" --- 1. show the `EXPLAIN` 2. How could it if you don't have indexes? How mysql can know anything about dataset without scanning?

Comment: Why `LEFT OUTER` joins everywhere? Just changing to `INNER` should give the optimizer some more options. Do post the `explain` for both query (any SQL question is useless without that). How big is the _users table, exactly, and have you considered rewriting the JOIN back to it as an `EXISTS`?

Comment: @zerkms: No offense, but I think you would be in a better position to help with a more thorough reading of the question.

Comment: @Dmitri: I have read it. What I see: there was inacceptable slow query. Which was rewritten into an acceptable slow one. Then there are 2 questions: 1. is about correctness, which OP may prove themselves. 2. Is about "better way" which is obviously to add indexes. You guys may continue arguing if red or blue color makes the car looking faster, but the fact is - it does not matter. What matters is what engine and what driver you put inside. In another words: if one wants to optimize a query - then they need to use the tools that have been designed for such a task.

Comment: @zerkms: You keep insisting that there are "no indexes", which is not true. Here in the real world, external constraints sometimes force non-optimal solutions, in which case insisting that the optimal, but unavailable, solution is "better" is not constructive. There is nothing wrong with asking for a clearer/more idiomatic version of OP's solution.

Comment: @Dmitri: there is nothing wrong indeed, but it's not efficient. You see, 8 hours passed and we are discussing query optimization **without** execution plans. `EXPLAIN` must be the first thing to look at. Do you think it's possible to provide advices about query optimization without execution plans? How do you know how exactly the query is executed? Well, I'm not insisting on anything anymore, I see this discussion useless.

Comment: "IRL the relevant columns are INTs:", that's a very different story than a VARCHAR... "Note that there's no (accessible) index on friend_fb_id.", WHY? This is your foreign key and it makes a lot of sense to create an index on this one. EXPLAIN ANALYZE can show you the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use temporary tables? If so, give this a try...

```
drop table if exists friend_count; 

create temporary table friend_count ( 
  user_name varchar not null primary key, 
  friend_count int not null
); 

create index on friend_count (friend_count);

insert into friend_count select 
  user_name,
  count(*)
from _fb_friends
/* place more code here necessary to count only the firends within a smaller
  group of users */ 
group by user_name; 

select 
  me.user_name,
  me.fb_id
from _users me
join friend_count fc on fc.user_name = me.user_name
where fc.friend_count >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a large enough data set to check on, but see if this performs any faster.

```
select me.*
from _users me
where 2=(select count(1) from
          (select 1 from _fb_friends ff 
           join _users friend on friend.fb_id=ff.friend_fb_id
           where ff.user_name=me.user_name
           limit 2) x
         )
```